# how to uninstall web2py?

Tags: uninstallation, web2py

I installed web2py in my production environment for an old project.
How can I completely remove it now that I don't need it anymore?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not install web2py because web2py has no installation (except for pip release this week). It just runs from the folder where you put it. Just delete that folder.

If you use the web2py-setup-ubuntu.sh script than web2py is in /home/www-data/web2py

If you used the new "pip install web2py" just do "pip uninstall web2py"

Comment: There's a load of other files and folders related to web2py in `/home/www-data`. It isn't all neatly tucked under `/home/www-data/web2py`

Answer (score 1):

There is more to it than just deleting `/home/www-data/web2py`. The script web2py-setup-ubuntu.sh overwrites `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` (without creating a backup...). You might want to remove the whole web2py WSGIdaemon setup in this file in order to prevent confusion with another WSGI engine.The install script also sets up SSL with keys, not sure how that could interfere with other HTTPS services, for example. And the install script installs a couple more things (to no harm other than disk space I guess), you better take a look at it if you want a clean uninstall.